# how to modify data in a DetailsView Databound event

Tags: c#, data-binding, detailsview

I'm using a detailsview with an sqldatasource in the aspx page.
I'm trying to do some pre and post processing on some of the fields - basically to convert a html list to a newline separated list for editing and back to html to store in the database.

The post-processing in ItemUpdating is easy enough but the pre-processing in DataBound is messy...

```
protected void DetailsView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DetailsView1.Rows.Count > 2)
    {
        string s =((DataRowView)DetailsView1.DataItem).Row.ItemArray[2].ToString();


        TextBox box1 = (TextBox) DetailsView1.FindControl("textbox1");
        if (box1 != null)
        {
            box1.Text = preprocess(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Its the fragility of

`string s=((DataRowView)DetailsView1.DataItem).Row.ItemArray[2].ToString();`

that upsets me. I'm sure I am missing something (more than one thing) obvious!

I guess I was hoping to do something more like my ItemUpdating...

`e.NewValues["threeline"] = postprocess(e.NewValues["threeline"].ToString());`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use DataKeys and DataItemIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957033/how-to-use-datakeys-and-dataitemindex)

Comment: I guess you found the solution already in the 10 years which have elapsed so far. But look into adding the field you need into DataKeys property so that it is directly available off the control rather than digging into the generated control tree.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to Asp.Net 4.0+ and use `ObjectDataSource`.

Set `ObjectDataSource.TypeName` to the data access object `Type.FullName`.
Set `ObjectDataSource.DataObjectTypeName` to the DTO `Type.FullName`.
Set `ObjectDataSource.SelectMethod` to the data access object method that get a `IQueryable<MyDto>`.
Set `DetailsView1.DataSourceID` to `ObjectDataSource.ID`.
Set `DetailsView1.ItemType` to the DTO `Type.FullName`.

And does somthing like this:

```
var item = DetailsView1.DataItem as MyDTO;
if(item == null)
    return;

var box1 = (TextBox) DetailsView1.FindControl("textbox1");
if (box1 == null)
    return;

box1.Text = preprocess(item.PropertyName);
```