# Hiding fields in DetailsView from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sorry if this is elementary, I'm new to .Net and have looked around, but maybe I'm not searching the right terms.

I have a DetailsView that I loaded in design view.  I'd like some of these fields to only show to certain users.  So I was thinking in codebehind, I could hide the other fields.  I'd also like to change the HeaderText for some of these fields in codebehind.

However, I also need this DetailsView to be editable.  If the fields are hidden for some users, I wasn't sure how that would effect anything.  Will it update all fields, even the hidden ones?

Only certain users should see the edit button as well.

Does anyone have any tips on how to go about something like this?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2192327/690329) how to find and modify controls in detailsview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your page class create a boolean field to represent whether the control should be visible and set this value in page_load.  (Note: Authentication.IsAuthorized is just an example of how to determine the field, replace this with your own code)

```
public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected bool showField = false;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        showField = Authentication.IsAuthorized(User.Identity.Name);
    }
}
```

Now bind to this field in your control.  Note that this requires the use of template fields rather than bound fields.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblHiddenField" runat="server" Visible='<%# showField %>' />
```

This will work for your buttons as well provided they're in a template field.  I've used bound fields in the past and some nasty foreach loops to find the controls I want to hide, but honestly this is the more straight-forward way to do this IMHO.

Comment: If you want this to work for buttons, you have to databind like `button1.DataBind();` as long as you are using <%# %>

Comment: @Subterfuge This is what I was looking for.  Wasn't sure how to articulate it.  Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @afzalulh Databind will be called on the button automatically if it is in a template field.  Cineno28 - No problem!  Glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

To show only some of the fields use the following code:

```
DetailsView1.Fields[1].Visible = false;
```

To Change the header text use:

```
DetailsView1.Fields[1].HeaderText = "something";
```

Edit will allow only to edit the visible fields.

To make a the detailview editable use:

```
DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Edit);
```