# How to Dynamically hide Template fields in DetailsView

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a DetailsView that uses template fields. What I would like to happen is when a field value is "FTP" it will show the fields related to FTP otherwise it shows the fields related to SFTP.

I have read the SO Question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322294/hiding-fields-in-detailsview-from-codebehind). However, it doesn't seem to be working. I have tried changing the variable before and after I databind my DetailsView. Could someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Also, I need to do this with about 20 fields on this page alone so I am trying to avoid the ever complex loop structure using FindControl().

Here is some of my code.

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="REPRESENTATION_TYPELBL" runat="server" Visible='<%# showFTP %>'
        Text='<%# Bind("REPRESENTATION_TYPE") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected bool showFTP = false; // Tried initializing as class variable
protected bool showSFTP; // and also not initializing
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChooseFTPDisplay("SFTP"); // Tried setting it in Page_Load and not in Page_Load
    }
protected void FTPGetBind()
    {
        if (FTPLookupDDL.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            DataTable tbl = BL.GetFTPRow("FTPLookUpID"); // data retrieval
            //ChooseFTPDisplay((string)tbl.Rows[0]["FTP_MODE"]); // tried here
            FTPGetView.DataSource = tbl;
            FTPGetView.DataBind();
            ChooseFTPDisplay((string)tbl.Rows[0]["FTP_MODE"]); // tried here

        }
    }
private void ChooseFTPDisplay(string mode)
    {
        if (mode == "FTP")
        {
            showFTP = true;
            showSFTP = false;
        }
        else // Could be null or "SFTP"
        {
            showFTP = false;
            showSFTP = true;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

I have now tried this as well:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="REPRESENTATION_TYPE" runat="server" Visible='<%# (string)Eval("FTP_MODE") == "FTP" ? true: false%>' 
     Text='<%# Bind("REPRESENTATION_TYPE") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**UPDATE**

I did not provide enough information. I would like to hide the entire Field. That includes the Header, Item/Edit/Insert Template and any child controls. What I have above Works to hide individual controls but not the whole Field. 
Unfortunately, I can't just do this:

```
<TemplateField Visible='<%# boolValue %>' >...Stuff...</TemplateField>
```

because TemplateFields are not bindable.

Basically, I want the equivalent of:

```
DetailsView1.Fields[15].Visible = false;// 15 is the index of the field I want hidden
```

in the most efficient and scalable way I can do it. This form will almost certainly change in the future and I don't want someone to have to go back and figure out the index's of all 20+ fields that will need to be dynamically shown or hidden.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "it doesn't seem to be working"? What result do you get?

Comment: It just displays all the fields regardless of the Boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the example below.I wrote a simple class with three fields:

- Type
- IP
- Port

If you look at IP and Port fields you will notice that I wrote expressions on the `Visible` property of these fields to check if the `Type` is FTP or SFTP, this shows or hides the label accordingly.

**.ASPX:**

```
  <asp:DetailsView AutoGenerateRows="false" ID="detailsView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="detailsView_PageIndexChanging">
            <Fields>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Type") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IP") %>' Visible='<%# Eval("Type") == "FTP" ? true : false %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Port") %>' Visible='<%# Eval("Type") == "SFTP" ? true : false %>'  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class DetailsViewWithConditionalColumns : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
            this.BindData();
    }

    private void BindData()
    {
        var ftp1 = new FTPDetails { Type = "FTP", IP = "1.1.1.1", Port = "21" };
        var ftp2 = new FTPDetails { Type = "SFTP", IP = "2.2.2.2", Port = "22" };

        detailsView.DataSource = new List<FTPDetails> { ftp1, ftp2 };
        detailsView.DataBind();
    }

    protected void detailsView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, DetailsViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        detailsView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        this.BindData();
    }
}

public class FTPDetails
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public string Port { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It still shows all fields. Could it be related to when the details view is bound?

Comment: Do you have a property called Type in your data source and does it have values called either "FTP" or "SFTP"?I just wrote the code as an example, I have no idea what you named your properties.You should only use the code above as a guideline and adjust it accordingly to fit your needs

Comment: Before using it I did change "Type" to something meaningful to my data. I'll update my question.

Comment: Is it possible to Eval()/Bind() the same datafield multiple times?

Comment: I have updated my answer and included the code I used in the code behind file.Copy it as is into a new page and get my example working in your project.Go through the code and understand what I'm doing and how I'm binding the data to the details view control.Then once you understand it hopefully it will guide you to solving your problem

Comment: Yours code works as expected. I will have to look into this a bit more.

Comment: It's very simple - I have a property called Type on my data source which can either be "FTP" or "SFTP" that's why the visible expressions is this - <%# Eval("Type") == "SFTP" ? true : false %>.Just try and apply the same logic to your code but use YOUR property nae and available values.Please remeber to mark as answered if it helped you or at least upvote

Comment: I have figured out the problem. I asked the wrong question. What you provided will hide the label, textbox, or whatever which is great. However, what I actually need is for the entire row to be hidden. This includes the Header.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a similar issue, this is how I hid the fields I needed hidden. I realize that this is almost certainly not the best way of doing this but it works.

What I did was set some Boolean variables for each group of fields that were conditionally visible. Then every time the radio button was clicked it would change the Boolean variable accordingly. I used the TemplateFields `SortExpression` to group the fields that needed to be together.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SFTP_KNOWNHOST_KEY_ID *"
                        SortExpression="SFTP">
    // Stuff goes here
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="REPRESENTATION_TYPE
                        SortExpression="FTP_FIELD">
    // Stuff goes here
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FTPS_CACERTIFICATE_ID
                        SortExpression="FTPS">
    // Stuff goes here
</asp:TemplateField>


private static bool showFTP, showSFTP, showFTPS;

protected void FTP_MODEBtns_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string mode = FTP_MODEBtns.SelectedValue;
    if (mode == "FTP")
        {
            showFTP = true;
            showSFTP = false;
            showFTPS = false;
        }
        else
        {
            showFTP = false;
            showSFTP = true;
            showFTPS = false;
        }
    SetVisibility();
}

static internal void SetVisibility()
    {

        foreach (DataControlField f in FTPView.Fields)
        {
            string htext = f.SortExpression;  
            if (htext.Contains("SFTP"))
                f.Visible = showSFTP;
            else if (htext.Contains("FTP_FIELD"))
                f.Visible = showFTP;
            else if (htext.Contains("FTPS"))
                f.Visible = showFTPS;                
        }
    }
```